# Replacing HTML source of an iframe document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on a page that will display the contents of a database field. The contents are in HTML format and includes an entire webpage

```
<html>
  <title>Some title</title>
  <style type="text/css">
     /* CSS content here */
  </style>
  <body>
    <!-- body content here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to display all of this inside another webpage so I thought using an iframe would allow me to negate any css from the parent page.  However, I cannot figure out how to overwrite the contents of the iframe document.

What I've done so far is retrieve the data and then use the following

```
$("#iframe_constainer")
  .find('iframe:first').contents().find('html:first').html(myHTML);
```

My web page includes a div called iframe_container which contains an iframe.

```
<div id="iframe_container"><iframe/></div>
```

This is working okay, but the contents of `myHTML` are getting wrapped inside `html` tags.  So the effect is like this

```
<html>
  <html>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       /* CSS content here */
    </style>
    <body>
      <!-- body content here -->
    </body>
  </html>
</html>
```

I know it's because I'm finding the html tag in the iframe and changing the HTML.  Is there a way to overwrite the entire document using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery for this, just use `document.write` to write content to the iframe to completely replace iframe's document.

E.g. (in plain vanilla JS)

```
document.getElementById("myIframeId").contentWindow.document.write(myHTML);
```

Comment: This doesn't replace, but instead appends to the iframe document

Comment: @Kurren You are right, every time page render it's apppendf the same content. if you found any solution then pls share here

Answer (score 2):

Opening the document and closing afterwards will fix the issue with appending the content

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeID');
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(htmlData);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```